# Why no exception when finally has return clause

Tags: java, try-catch-finally

The code snap is like below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(echo("jjj"));
}

public static String echo(String str) {
    try {
        int a = 1/0;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    } finally {
        return str;
    }
}
```

Why can I get the output and no exception occurs?
And if I put the return clause out of finally, then exception occurs.
How could `return`(in `finally`) stop `exception`?

Comment: Check this out: https://www.google.com/webhp?q=return%20from%20finally

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is specified pretty explicitly in the [Java Language Specification section 14.20.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2), which says:

> A try statement with a finally block is executed by first executing
>   the try block. Then there is a choice:
>
> - If execution of the try block completes normally, then the finally
>     block is executed, and then there is a choice:
>
>   - If the finally block completes normally, then the try statement completes normally.
>   - If the finally block completes abruptly for reason S, then the try statement completes abruptly for reason S.
> - **If execution of the try block completes abruptly because of a
>     throw of a value V**, then there is a choice:
>
>   - **If the run-time type of V is assignment compatible with a catchable exception class of any catch clause of the try statement,
>       then the first (leftmost) such catch clause is selected. The value V
>       is assigned to the parameter of the selected catch clause, and the
>       Block of that catch clause is executed. Then there is a choice:**
>
>     - If the catch block completes normally, then the finally block is executed. Then there is a choice:
>
>       - If the finally block completes normally, then the try statement completes normally.
>       - If the finally block completes abruptly for any reason, then the try statement completes abruptly for the same reason.
>     - **If the catch block completes abruptly for reason R, then the finally block is executed. Then there is a choice:**
>
>       - If the finally block completes normally, then the try statement completes abruptly for reason R.
>       - **If the finally block completes abruptly for reason S, then the try statement completes abruptly for reason S (and reason R
>           is discarded).**

(Note that "throwing an exception" and "returning a value" count as "completing abruptly.")